# Sorting out a list alphabetically then ascending

Tags: c#, sorting

Imagine I have a list with the following values:

```
{"abc","04","bca","10","cba","11","01"}
```

if I use normal c# OrderBy() on the list it will result in this:

```
{"01","04","10","11","abc","bca","cba"}
```

but what I intend is a bit the opposite:

```
{"abc","bca","cba","01","04","10","11"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about below solution,

```
var input = new List<string>(){"abc","04","bca","10","cba","11","01"};
var result = input.OrderBy(x => x.All(Char.IsDigit));

//You can further sort it, using `ThenBy()`
var result = input.OrderBy(x => x.All(Char.IsDigit)).ThenBy(x => x);
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qsPqa)

---

**Explaination:**

- `x.All(Char.IsDigit)` returns `true` if the all characters are digits. Otherwise it return `false`.
- As we are writing it as a predicate, `OrderBy()` will sort the list based on the result of `.All()`.
- All `false` values will come first(In our case, non numeric strings) and all numeric strings will sort at the end

Comment: This doesn't sort the values within, though.

Comment: Just need to add a `.ThenBy(x => x)` to do the extra sort.

Comment: The 'intended output' does show they are sorted. `ThenBy(x => x)` ought to do it.

Comment: @CharlesMager is correct. Adding the ThenBy(x=> x) does the trick. I'll mark it as correct anyways. Apreciate it :)

Comment: Instead of checking if all chars are digits, just do it for the first if text and numbers are mixed: `var result = input.OrderBy(x => x.Select(Char.IsDigit).FirstOrDefault()).ThenBy(x => x);
`

Comment: @Oliver - why `x.Select(Char.IsDigit).FirstOrDefault()` instead of `x.Any(Char.IsDigit)` ?

Comment: @RandRandom Because the ordering depends on the first character being a digit and not any character.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the list by Regex into two lists, alphabet and numerical, then sort and then join them again.

Comment: I thought about it but i also thought there could be a simpler, one line way, to do it :)